# Better performance than double SQLite inner join

Tags: sqlite

I have three tables (everything is oversimplified for the question)

```
Student
---
StudentId (primary key)
UniversityId (indexed)
CityId (indexed)
StudentName


University
---
UniversityId (primary key)
UniversityName


City
---
CityId (primary key)
CityName
```

I want to print out all the student names, but if names are the same, I want to order first by the CityName where they are from, and then by the UniversityName.

So, I have a simple query like this one:

```
select s.* from student s 
inner join university u on s.UniversityId = u.UniversityId 
inner join city c on s.CityId = c.CityId 
order by s.StudentName asc, c.CityName asc, u.UniversityName asc
```

Is there a way to improve performance of this in any way, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexes on `UniversityId` and `CityId` are not needed.

The ORDER BY could be optimized with an index on `StudentName`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, StudentName is already indexed, forgot to add that. In this case I really need just UniversityName and CityName from University and City tables, and in reality I have far more columns than in the example above. So, there's nothing more I could do to perhaps ignore the rest of the columns and somehow speed things up?

Comment: You could create covering indexes, but that would not help much. If you really need more speed, it might be more productive to optimize the hardware or the software configuration.